# How does this Stradella Bass System fingering work

Tags: fingering, accordion

I am trying to learn the Bayan (Accordion) and the book I am following has the following piece as it's trying to introduce the left hand bass system.

[image]

In the first measure I can understand the position for the first three notes (C, D and E) but I am not able to understand how the F note (played with a button right next to the C button) is expected to be played using the 2nd finger.

Is it a different button than the one next to the C button or is it basically really quick fingering change that I need to learn ?

Comment: That's certainly an odd fingering and not playable on Stradella Bass. My guess is either a typo or that it's not for a Stradella bass after all. Maybe free bass? What book is it?

Comment: I know accordions can be "upside down" depending on where they are from. Perhaps your accordion is not from the same country? Or perhaps I did not understand the issue, is your hands too small so shifting would be needed? I think accordion player's hands fly all over the place (I can't play anything advanced myself and don't have one at home).

Answer (score 1):

[image]This is bayan free bas system. F is in the 1st line, suitable for 2nd finger. C is in 3rd line, suitable for 4th finger and E is on 2nd line, suitable for 3rd finger. [image]